# SlidingMenu: переход между активити

Tags: button, activity, sliding, android

Здравствуйте.

Возникла следующая проблема. Подключил библиотеку [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu), создал xxx.xml(боковое меню) и xxx.class, на .xml(layout который  добавил кнопку, в .class написал следующий код:

```
public class Xxx extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

     Button buttonxxx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.xxx);

        buttonxxx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonxxx);
        buttonxxx.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

        public void onClick(View v) {
             switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.buttonxxx:
                     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Xxxtwo.class);
                     startActivity(intent);
                  break;} 
             }
 }
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а что ты ждешь? и причем тут боковое меню?

Comment: Жду чтоб при нажатии на кнопку(buttonxxx) переходило на другую Activity(Xxxtwo.class). Боковое меню(xxx) при том что кнопка(buttonxxx) на нем находится, чтоб его вызвать надо провести пальцем по экрану слева на право. Оно(xxx) вызывается, кнопка(buttonxxx) на нем есть, но при нажатии она ни как не реагирует.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы Slidingmenu во второй activity тоже было активно? Дело в том, что Slidingmenu предполагает переключение фрагментов(Fragments) в рамках одной acnivity, а не переход между разными activity при выборе того или иного пункта Slidingmenu.
Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то могу объяснить поподробнее.

Comment: Да вы правильно поняли. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при выборе определённого пункта из бокового меню появлялся список ListView. Есть ListFragment, но тогда как отображать само боковое меню?

Comment: Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, пожалуйста, задайте его, нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Укажите ссылку на этот вопрос, если это обеспечивает необходимый контекст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала нужно инициализировать Slidingmenu в MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{

private Fragment mContent;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //В content_frame должен быть просто FrameLayout. Так же, как и в slidingmenu_frame
        setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            mContent = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "mContent");
        if (mContent == null)
            mContent = new Fragment1();

         // View основной, видимой части
        setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent)
            .commit();

        // установка View для SlidingMenu
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.slidingmenu_frame);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame, new MenuFragment())
            .commit();

        // настройка SlidingMenu
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(70);
    }

//Также нужно добавить метод для замены фрагментов. Он будет заменять фрагменты при выборе того или иного пункта SlidingMenu

public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
    mContent = fragment;
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
    .commit();
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}
}
```

Также хорошо бы добавить немного кода для вызова SlidingMenu:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if ( getSlidingMenu().isMenuShowing()) {
        getSlidingMenu().toggle();
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        this.getSlidingMenu().toggle();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        this.getSlidingMenu().toggle();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Теперь самое время заняться меню. Как видно, при инициализации меню мы вызываем класс MenuFragment. Нужно создать новый класс MenuFragment. Вот что в нём примерно должно быть:

```
public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment {
    private String menuItems[];

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    //Тут задаем имена для элементов SlidingMenu. В папке values нужно создать соответсвующие ресурсы
    menuItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.screens);
/**Создадим кастомный адаптер, если мы хотим для каждого пункта SlidingMenu в придачу к тексту установить иконку. Если иконка вам не нужна, используйте обычный ArrayAdapter<String>.*/
    MyCustomAdapter myAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this.getActivity(), 
            R.layout.slidingmenu_item, menuItems);
    setListAdapter(myAdapter);
}
//Загрузка того или иного фрагмента при выборе соответствующего элемента меню

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
    Fragment newContent = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        newContent = new FirstFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        newContent = new SecondFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        newContent = new ThirdFragment();
        break;
    }
    if (newContent != null)
        switchFragment(newContent);
    }

    //Теперь сам метод switchFragment, осуществляющий замену фрагментов.
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if (getActivity() == null)
        return;

    if (getActivity() instanceof MainActivity) {
        MainActivity fca = (MainActivity) getActivity();
        fca.switchContent(fragment);
    }
    }

    //А вот и наш кастомный адаптер для установки иконок к каждому пункту меню

public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context_;
        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            context_ = context;
        }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context_);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingmenu_item, parent, false);
        TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_title);
        label.setText(menuItems[position]);

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.row_icon);

      //Вместо MenuItem1 ваше название пункта меню, вместо image1 - ваша картинка
        if (menuItems[position].equalsIgnoreCase("MenuItem1")) {
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        } else 
            if (menuItems[position].equalsIgnoreCase("MenuItem2")) {
                icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
            } else 
                if (menuItems[position].equalsIgnoreCase("MenuItem3")) {
                    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.image3);
                } 
        return row;
    }
}
}
```

Теперь можно создавать классы FirstFragment, SecondFragment и ThirdFragment, наcледующие Fragment, и заполнять их контентом. Они и будут тремя "экранами", переключаемыми в зависимости от выбора того или иного пункта SlidingMenu.

Comment: Спрашивайте, если что. Как раз недавно сам разбирался со SlidingMenu

Answer (score 0):

id кнопки R.id.buttonxxxа вы ловите R.id.lschedulecalls

Comment: Извиняюсь. При добавлении кода в вопрос решил поменять названия кнопки, layout'a и class'а т.к. они не очень эстетичные. Но там когда менял не заметил, что указывается id.

Comment: не работал с  SlidingMenu, но думаю проблема в том что Xxx наследуется от обычной  Activity, к слову гугл допилил в сапорте боковое меню довольно таки удобно 
http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html   
p.s. даже когда пишется только для себя имена должны быть осмыслены